# Recursion C++ Display Middle Node

Tags: c++, recursion

How would I modify this display_all function to only display the middle node recursively?

My code to display all backwards

```
int display_middle(node * head)
{

  if(!head)
    return 0;

  int count = 0;

  ++count;

  display_middle(head -> next);

  cout << head -> data << " "; 

}
```

Comment: This is actually not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as required. However, if this is a list you have to count all nodes before you can determine the middle. As you do it recursively, the total count is known when recursion terminates. Thus, you can compare the result of the recursive call (the total count) with the current (local) `count` and should be able to find out when "backtracking" hits the middle. Please, try this and edit your question with the modified code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using two pointers, one which proceeds one step at a time and a second which proceeds two steps at a time, then when the one which proceeds two steps at a time hits NULL, you know you've hit the middle node with the node which proceeds one step at a time. Below is a rough sketch of the code, you'll need to add boundary checks and validation.

```
int display_middle_rec(node * head, node * next)
{

  if((!next) || (!(next->next)))
    return head->data;

  return display_middle_rec(head->next, next->next->next);

}

int display_middle(node * head)
{
  return display_middle_rec(head, head);
}
```

In main

```
std::cout<<display_middle(head);
```

Comment: I am also not allowed to modify what's passed into the function. I have to use  display_middle(node * head) . I guess I could just declare node * next within the function?

Comment: This also seems to seg fault when the list is an odd number, but runs fine if the list has an even number of nodes

Comment: You will need to add checks for when next->next is NULL, the code was just meant as pseudocode. If you're not allowed to change the prototype, you could offload the search to a second function which will do what is shown here.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a pseudo-code to get you started, please work out corner cases, such as zero length list, mid point for odd/even list length etc.

```
int count = 0;
int finalCount = 0;
int middle = 0;
int returnIndex  = 0;


int display_middle(node * head) {

if(!head) {
  finalCount = count;
  returnIndex = finalCount;
  mid = finalCount/2; // Handle mid point for odd/Even list length here. This is 
                    // For illustration purposes.
  return 0;
}
//int count = 0;

++count;

display_middle(head -> next);

if(returnIndex == mid) {cout << head -> data << " ";}
returnIndex = returnIndex - 1; //Work out if this statement needs to go before the previous one or is OK here.

}
```

Comment: I guess I should have added too. I am not allowed to use global variables.

Comment: Hmm.. then we may have to adopt a different approach, does node->data store integer? I will assume that and modify..

Comment: Yes. Node -> data does store int. I've been trying to modify the count to count nodes and then divide by 2 (which I was hoping would give the number of half the list) and then somehow on the way back using that number to output the middle node's data

Comment: I was trying to then store the listLength and recursionCount in extra nodes but I like user3336523's solution better. I think this is what is expected. The turtle/rabbit paradigm usually used for detecting loops, but this is a good use for that as shows.

Answer (score 0):

This works, no need to keep an extra variable count.

Call `display_middle(struct node *head)` in your function.

```
void display_middle_recurse(struct node *slow,struct node *fast){

    if(fast->next==NULL || fast==NULL){
        cout << slow->data;
        return;     
    } 

    fast=fast->next->next;
    slow=slow->next;
    printMiddleRecurse(slow ,fast );

}

void display_middle(struct node *head){

        void display_middle_recurse(head,head);

}
```